# ZFS - Pool name has the same name as Dataset (volume)?

Tags: zfs

I messed up my pool by doing zfs send...receive So I got the following :

```
zpool list
NAME    SIZE  ALLOC   FREE    CAP  DEDUP  HEALTH  ALTROOT
rpool   928G  17.3G   911G     1%  1.00x  ONLINE  -
tank1   928G  35.8G   892G     3%  1.00x  ONLINE  -
```

So I have "tank1" pool.

```
zfs get all tank1
NAME   PROPERTY              VALUE                  SOURCE
tank1  type                  volume                 -
```

Haa...I also have "tank1" as a volume....

So I wanted to delete the volume :

```
zfs destroy tank1
cannot destroy 'tank1': dataset already exists
```

So let me delete the pool...Please...

```
zpool destroy tank1
cannot open 'tank1': operation not applicable to datasets of this type
```

Another try : (just want to rename...)

```
zfs rename tank1 tank1/kuku
cannot create 'tank1/kuku': parent is not a filesystem
```

How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: What does a 'zfs list -rt all tank1' show?

Answer (score 1):

Exactly the same thing happened to me. It was on testing pool so I just scrapped it but I filed a bug report with zfs on linux here:
https://github.com/zfsonlinux/zfs/issues/3699

behlendorf responded with possible fix:

> I'd try to fix your pool by importing it with a different name to
>   avoid the conflict. You can do this with zpool import old-pool-name
>   new-pool-name. Once you sort it out and rename/destroy the offending
>   zvol you can export/import the pool to restore the original name.